# MODIFICAR VENTANA MODAL

Tags: javascript, html, modal, ventana, funcion

Verán, necesito que los datos que me arrojan la tabla, el registro no se abran en la ventana modal.
Necesito que se abra en un página. me podrían ayudar. (Soy nuevo, tal vez sea algo tan sencillo pero me está volviendo loco).
Alguien que que pueda solucionarlo por favor.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.view', function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var action = 'detalles';
        jQuery('.modal-title').html("DETALLES");
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:"vistas/fetch_single.php",
            method:"POST",
            
            data:{id:id, action:action},
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(json){
                jQuery ('#viewRow').modal('show');              
                jQuery('#at-codigo').text(json.codigo);             
                jQuery('#at-nombres').text(json.nombres);
                jQuery('#at-apellidos').text(json.apellidos);
                jQuery('#at-genero').html(json.genero);             
                jQuery('#at-estado').html(json.estado);
                jQuery('#at-fecha').text(json.fecha);                       
                
            }
        })
    });
```

```html
<div class="modal" id="viewRow" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Ver registro</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="card card-primary card-outline">
                        <div class="card-body box-profile">
......
```

---

Claro! éste es el código

```html
echo json_encode($output);
        }elseif($_POST["action"]=="detalles"){
        $output = array();
        $statement = $conexion->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM usuarios 
        WHERE id = '".$_POST["id"]."' 
        LIMIT 1"
        );
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            if($row['estado']==NULL or $row['estado']==0){
                $estado = '<div class="badge badge-warning badge-pill">Pendiente</div>';
                }elseif($row['estado']==-1){
                $estado = '<div class="badge badge-secondary badge-pill">Cancelado</div>';  
                }elseif($row['estado']==1){
                $estado = '<div class="badge badge-success badge-pill">Atendido</div>'; 
            }
            
            $output["codigo"] = $row["codigo"];     
            $output["fecha"] = $row["fecha"];
            $output["nombres"] = $row["nombres"];
            $output["apellidos"] = $row["apellidos"];
            $output["genero"] = $row["genero"];
            $output["estado"] = $estado;
            $output["id"] = $row["id"];
        }
        
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español!  Tu ejemplo esta incompleto, no vemos donde esta la clase `.view` ni a que corresponde. Tampoco sabemos lo que contiene el PHP denominado `vistas/fetch_single.php`, que seguramente devuelve un json con los datos a rellenar por jquery tal como lo has puesto. Aún así, aunque tengamos esos datos, mucho me temo que tu solución pasa por una reescritura completa de un nuevo script en php que haga lo que tu pides, muy parecido al fetch_single.php, y cambios en el javascript proporcionado para que no te siga enviando la petición ajax. Mucho curro que deberias hacer tu.

Comment: Si agregas el código de **vistas/fetch_single.php** en tu pregunta, tal vez sea más sencillo entender lo que quieres lograr.